# Traversing Linked List

Tags: java, class, linked-list

I am new to the Linked list. In void main(), I understood that **Start** is the object of class **Node** so using that object we have called **next** variable of node class like **Start.next** but I didn't get the line **Start.next.next** what it means?

There is only one variable next so how come Start is calling next.next?
And the program is working correctly.

```
public class list {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Node Start = new Node(1);
        Start.next = new Node(2);
        Start.next.next = new Node(3);
        Start.next.next.next = new Node(4);
        for (Node list = Start; list != null; list = list.next) {
            System.out.println(list.data + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("Null");
    }
}

class Node {

    int data;
    Node next;
    Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
1
2
3
4
Null
```

Comment: ``Start.next`` is of type ``Node``, just like ``Start`` itself. That means that ``Start.next`` has a field called ``next``, too. That's the way the list elements are linked to the next one, hence the name linked list.

Comment: Note that Java naming conventions suggest to always start a variable name (methods also) with a **lowercase** letter and just use uppercase for classes. It is easier to differentiate at first glance then. So it should be `Node start =new Node(1);` instead of `Node Start =new Node(1);` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
Node Start =new Node(1);
Start.next = new Node(2);
```

`Start` is a `Node` that has a member variable named `next` that is also a `Node`. (And that `Node` also has its own `next` node, and so on. Every `Node` has its own `next`.)  So when you say `Start.next.next` you're accessing the next node in the list. (The 3rd node overall, the second one after the `Start` node.)

Answer (score 0):

`Start.next.next` is the member variable of the `Node next` present in `Start`.

Here is the break down:

1. `Node Start` contains `Node next`.
2. `Node next` contains its own member variable `Node next`.

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`Start` is an instance of the `Node` class. The `Node` class contains members such as `data` and `next`, where `data` is an integer, and `next` is a `Node`. Therefore, we can equivalently say:

```
 Node Start = new Node();
 Node Second = new Node();
 Start.next = Second;
 Node Third = new Node();
 Second.next = Third; /* And this is equivalent to Start.next.next = Third,
             because Start.next and Second refer to the same object instance. */
```

Essentially, Start.next is another instance of `Node` and therefore, the object referred to by `Start.next` will also contain a `.next` member.

Answer (score 0):

You can understand it better if you can think it is like this.
Consider the `Node` class is a Person which have some data and a father :

```
class Person {
    //some data
    Person father;
    Person(/*some data*/) {
        /*this.(some data) = some data;*/
    }
}
```

The son is a `Person`, the son has a some data and father, father also is a Person, father have also some data and have also a father which is (grand father), and so on ...